# Getting excel row and column index in c#

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I've an excel file like this,

[image: MyExcelFile]
now I try to search inside this file and trying to get the index of that cell, **as an example** if the user types Date in a textbox I want to get 3 as return from my method, I don't need the row index I know it will be always in first row so I just need the column index. **As an another example** lets say user typed Category in the textbox so I want to get the number "8" from my method and go on, I've searched for it but couldn't find a code that will work for me..
If I can find the column index I'll put it into my SaveAsXML method so I can pass the value to my xml method.

Comment: Do you know how to loop through cells? If so then just loop through the first row's cells until you find given text

Comment: Yes I was just typing this way as my alternative, but I wanna know if I can search my whole range for a specified text and if its find the text I'm searching it will give me its index, this way will be more effecient if not I'll pull all my first lane into a string array and open an if statement, if my array value match the textbox value I'll simple save an integet as NAME_COLUMN and then I can use xlRange.Cells[i,NAME_COLUMN] and so on

Comment: [Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4x1k99a.aspx) could help

Comment: I've looked for it but its not returning the index of searched value

Comment: The Find method approach should return the range of cells when it finds the text. And from the range you can identify which cell it is. What output do you get?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I get C1 when I tried it, the C changes but 1 is always fixed since I only check first row, I've managed another way actually its kinda troll way but it worked out. I get all my first row into string array then compared the textbox text with stringArray[i], did this in a for that counts for ColumnsCount so If this 2 matches I've do this:   if (FirstRow[i] == txtVideoPath.Text) {  VideoPathCol = (i + 1); }
after that when I need VideoPath I simply used this : if (VideoPathCol != 0) { FILE_PATH = xlRange.Cells[i, VideoPathCol].Value2; }